# Access internal ip (home server) through double NAT (router + ISP)

Tags: vpn, ip, router, nat, isp

I have home server (debian-like machine) inside my wifi-network. I wan't to access it over http (for transmission-daemon web interface) and over ssh (to administrate it).

The issue is that there are two nats in the network: my router's and my ISP's. I can port-forward on my router & use ddns (to get fixed ip), but I can't traverse my ISP's nat.

What are my options? I guess VPN here can be a solution, is it true? If it is, is it correct that I need to setup VPN on third-party server and on my router?

[image: scheme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPN is your best option, because you dont have control over your ISP router, the issue must be on your server side network when goes to wan, if both host are Linux you can use OpenVPN here a Wiki of Open VPN on Debian:

https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN

Answer (score 1):

Most defiantly a VPN server or VPN Server Software on your home device or software tool like LetMeIn..

Since you do not have access to your ISP's Modem to do any kind of port forwarding.  It really limits what you can do.

If its just the data you need to access then maybe a cloud service like dropbox, onedrive etc.  Then you can share the data you need.

Hope this helps a bit.  Cheers..